# How to find out the number of files types in a directory

Tags: bash, awk, dash-shell

So i am trying to write a script to search through a directory and find the number files with the same type. I tried this:

`find $directory -type f | file -b $SAVEFILES | cut -c1-40 | sort -n | uniq -c | sort -nr |`

but the number of how many times the the same type is there is before the type 
and look like this:

```
    168 ASCII TEXT
```

How do I access value of the number and store it and afterwards move it after the text like this:

```
ASCII TEXT: 168
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Append with GNU sed:

```
| sed 's/^ *\([0-9]\+\) \(.*\)/\2: \1/'
```

or

```
| sed -r 's/^ *([0-9]+) (.*)/\2: \1/'
```

Comment: When i added this to my code it didn't change anything.